# Collect Tracking Code Question

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm working to implement the Collect Tracking code.  I've added the head and body piece with the ID correctly set.

I.e. head:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://XXX.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js"></script>`

and body:

```
<script>
  _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "XXX"]);
  _etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);
</script>
```

Yet.  I'm not seeing sessions being recorded in Einstein, looking in the email recommendations.  I'm expecting to see sessions counting up.  Is that incorrect?  It does say it's receiving data, but none of the counters are going up.

Any ideas?

Comment: The counters are sometimes few hours behind. If you only recently enabled the script, give it 24h and check once more

Comment: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000KPMeQAO&title=base-collect-tracking-code-always-shows-0-in-status-console

Comment: This still appears to be an issue for me, with no data being seen in Einstein logs.  SF recommends using other methods to verify data being collected on basic page views, but offers no guidance.  Anyone know of another reporting view in Marketing Cloud to use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see on your code the line

```
_etmc.push([“setUserInfo”, {“email”: “INSERT_EMAIL_OR_UNIQUE_ID”}]);
```

I would say that's why this is not working as there's no data to associate with each event.

There's a very nice mini tutorial [here](https://www.marketingcloud.today/personalization-builder-setup-part1/) to achieve this first step you are trying on.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mario!  I've been trying to figure out if this setUserInfo bit is required.  Most of our sessions on the website are unauthenticated.  Is it required?

I was expecting to see sessions regardless of this, just not having them user identified.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: setUserInfo is not required- only if you need to use your recommendations in emails

Comment: only as @LukasLunow noted here and by the context I understood You are looking to use email recommendations as that's the collect.js part of.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you both so much.

Comment: And as an extra bonus, if you guys don't mind, In terms of setting the user info... is it normal to do that via URL?  as I said our use case has limited interactivity with the login.  So I'm assuming parsing a url parameter would be the way to go?

Comment: You can pass it in url, but make sure it is e.g. hashed: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/297841/36623